# Me tira una exception al llamar un procedure (oracle) desde java

Tags: java, oracle

Estoy ejecutando un procedure desde java. El procedure modifica unas tablas y comitea correctamente los cambios realizados pero al backend tira exception.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public void deleteUser(String email) throws ****PersistenceException {
        try{
            Connection connection = ((SessionImpl) currentSession()).connection();            

            String sProc = PL_BLOCK_BEGIN + PKG_PID + SP_DELETE + SP_PARAMS_D + PL_BLOCK_END;

            stmt_act = connection.prepareCall( sProc );
            stmt_act.setString(1, email);            
            stmt_act.executeUpdate();

            stmt_act.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ****PersistenceException(String.valueOf("Error al consultar el procedure delete, error devuelto por el procedure: " + e.getMessage() ));
        }
    }
```

El mensaje de error que tira es:

> Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

Comment: Parece que tienes una confusión entre Hibernate y JDBC. Te conectaste vía JDBC pero usas código de Hibernate. Son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: dentro del `catch` coloque un `e.printStackTrace()` para obtener más información, puede pasar que no se ejecuta la transacción solicitada y el error que presenta es una consecuancia del error original.

Comment: Agrege  el e.printStackTrace y trae el mismo error.